# Rails - Passing Parameters through link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, model, activeadmin

I want to create an Add to Watchlist column + link  after the description field ,so the selected movie to be stored on another rb. page from the admin section called "Watchlist".

The concept is similar to a Shopping Cart,passing the data from one page to another.

How's that possible in ActiveAdmin?

I would appreciate your hints and advices.

[image: The Page]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with ActiveAdmin, but if your question is how to pass parameters through link_to, try this:

```
link_to 'Somewhere', some_path(param_1: 'foo', param_2: 'bar')
```

When you click through, the params should be present in the query string and in the params hash that Rails provides. You can pull out the values with:

```
params[:param_1]
params[:param_2]
```

Comment: I will try this soon. Thank you